# Initializing custom class in settings file

Tags: c#, serialization, devexpress, settings, dockpanel

In my WinForms C# Application I am attempting to save a custom class in a settings file. here is my current code:

```
public class PanelSaver : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
  private DockingStyle ds;
  System.Drawing.Point location;
  System.Drawing.Size panelSize;

  [UserScopedSetting()]
  [SettingsSerializeAs(System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
  public DockingStyle Style
  {
     get { return ds; }
     set { ds = value; }
  }
  public System.Drawing.Point Location
  {
     get { return location; }
     set { location = value; }
  }
  public System.Drawing.Size Size
  {
     get { return panelSize; }
     set { panelSize = value; }
  }
}
```

The DockingStyle variable comes from DevExpress Dockpanels.

Here are the objects being used in the Settings file :

[image]

When I attempt to use these variables, by passing them into this function:

```
private void DockPanelSave(PanelSaver savingPanel, DockPanel realDockingPanel)//
{
   try
   {
      savingPanel.Location = realDockingPanel.Location;
      savingPanel.Size = realDockingPanel.Size;
      savingPanel.Style = realDockingPanel.Dock;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
      throw new NotSupportedException("You may have added a new panel, and may not have added a corresponding " +
      "settings variable to hold it in the Settings.settings file");
   }

}
```

I get a null error.

How should I initialize the values in the settings file? I am guessing I need to put in some kind of XML however I don't know the correct steps to take for generating it. Any directions on this or other reasons for my null error would be appreciated

Answer (score -2):

You can see by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995194/using-linq-to-pull-from-ienumerablexelement-and-store-in-data-table/9035905#9035905) I show how to do what you are asking.

It isn't the built in serialization, but you can define your class by my example and get the same result.

[Here's another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881930/how-to-mark-up-your-c-sharp-object-to-deserialize-this-xml/9882118#9882118),

[and another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323352/reading-an-xml-configuration-data-file-from-c-sharp/10325517#10325517)